# Scroll Menu in C

Tags: c, menu, scroll, key, selection

How can I create a menu with a scrolling selection like this:
[image]

I googled, but couldn't find anything.

My idea is to create a selection menu with up and down keys to select the option, but I don't know how to do it or if is it possible to do in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) ([screenshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aLinux-menuconfig.png)).

For tutorial, check this [HOW-TO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

Comment: is that available for Windows?

Comment: Yes. There a package for Windows available. Check [this](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm).

Comment: This is a library? This is compatible with all terminals?

Comment: This *should* be compatible.

Comment: It is a part of GnuWin which provides ports of tools to modern MS-Windows (Microsoft Windows 2000 / XP / 2003 / Vista / 2008 / 7). [More ...](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/summary.html)

Comment: @Bechir thanks for the feedback, it's nice to know that Windows still can be used for some cool stuff :-)

Answer (score -1):

Since you seem to be on windows, your options are:

- [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/)
- `ncurses` under [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com)